# Prepend script's directory to a string

Tags: python, file, module, path

When writing throwaway scripts it's often needed to load a configuration file, image, or some such thing from the same directory as the script. Preferably this should continue to work correctly regardless of the directory the script is executed from, so we may not want to simply rely on the current working directory.

Something like this works fine if defined within the same file you're using it from:

```
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

def prepend_script_directory(s):
    here = dirname(abspath(__file__))
    return join(here, s)
```

It's not desirable to copy-paste or rewrite this same function into every module, but there's a problem: if you move it into a separate library, and import as a function, `__file__` is now referencing some other module and the results are incorrect.

We could perhaps use this instead, but it seems like the `sys.argv` may not be reliable either.

```
def prepend_script_directory(s):
    here = dirname(abspath(sys.argv[0]))
    return join(here, s)
```

How to write `prepend_script_directory` robustly and correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would personally just `os.chdir` into the script's directory whenever I execute it. It is just:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.split(__file__)[0])
```

However if you did want to refactor this thing into a library, you are in essence wanting a function that is aware of its caller's state. You thus have to make it

```
prepend_script_directory(__file__, blah)
```

If you just wanted to write

```
prepend_script_directory(blah)
```

you'd have to do cpython-specific tricks with stack frames:

```
import inspect

def getCallerModule():
    # gets globals of module called from, and prints out __file__ global
    print(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_globals['__file__'])
```

Comment: @wim: that's why this is typically frowned upon =)

Comment: @ninjagecko: `os.path.split(__file__)[0]` is more simply and explicitly written as `os.path.dirname(__file__)`.

Comment: "Hacky debauchery" is bound to bite you or the next poor sod in the posterior. "If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea." http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

Comment: yeah it did bite me.. seems `__file__` is set , by `runpy` or module loader (i'm not sure when exactly), and it can be either a relative or absolute path depending on how you execute the script.  in the case of relative path it is NOT updated if you have called `os.chdir()`, so you would get wrong results using `os.path.abspath(__file__)` if you have earlier `os.chdir()` in the same file.  does that make sense?! :P

Answer (score -1):

I think the reason it doesn't smell right is that `$PYTHONPATH` (or `sys.path`) is the proper general mechanism to use.

Answer (score -1):

You want [pkg_resources](http://packages.python.org/distribute/pkg_resources.html#id22)

```
import pkg_resources
foo_fname = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, "foo.txt")
```

Comment: On my machine, this returns a path relative to the current directory, if `__name__` was imported from a relative path.  You may still wish to pass this through `os.path.abspath()` if that's a problem for you.